# Using HTML, JavaScript, and JQuery, can how can you assign a value to a variable by click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a "choose your own adventure" game using HTML, JavaScript, and JQuery (and CSS). I want to be able to set values for the player's character, such as gender (male/female), hair color (black, brown, blond, red), etc. Currently, I have `<a> </a>` tags with special Id's assigned to them, and have been trying to use JQuery to set the JavaScript variable based on what is clicked. Are there any suggested ways to do this, or a better way to do this?
For sample code, go here https://jsfiddle.net/Bob_Bobstien/5fdzhnw8/1/ or look below:
Sample code:

```
    <h3 id="gender">Are you a <a href="#" id="boy" class="genderchoice">boy</a> or a <a href="#" id="girl" class="genderchoice">girl</a>?</h3>
```

And here's the JQuery/JavaScript that didn't work (I'm new to JavaScript/Jquery, in case you couldn't tell):

```
    $('#boy').click(function(){
    gendervalue=male
});
$('#girl').click(function(){
    gendervalue=female
});
```

I had done some snooping around and thought that this setup *might* work, but evidently not, the value kept turning up undefined. I had defined the variable earlier in the script, right after the JQuery document.ready thing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var gendervalue;
$(otherJquery).things
```

Again, I saw that in a somewhat similar question, but maybe it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Are you looking for [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage)?

Comment: This is a good question, but it is somewhat broad and asking for the answerers to do a lot of work.  You may be able to get more help if you post some brief sections of the code  you have tried and let us know what's not working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign onclick event handlers to the buttons which will trigger a function, assigning the value of black to the hair etc.
As @xufox mentioned in the comment section, you can use `localstorage` to save those values locally and then retrieving whenever required, this can add a `Save Game` functionality to your code. If you can provide your code then all this can be explained with the help of it.

**With Pure JavaScript:**

```
 var genderValue;
 var boy = document.getElementById("boy");
 var girl = document.getElementById("girl");

 boy.onclick = myfunc;
 girl.onclick = myfunc;

 function myfunc(){
 if(this.id == "girl"){
 genderValue = "female";
 }else{
 genderValue = "male";
   }
 }
```

**With jQuery Code:**

```
$('#boy').on('click',function(){
var genderValue = "male";
});

$('#girl').on('click',function(){
var genderValue = "female";
});
```

> You will have to assign the value of `genderValue` to a string, and a string is always inside quotes, and that was the error.

**For `localStorage`:**

```
if(localStorage.getItem("genderValue") == null){

$('#boy').on('click',function(){
var genderValue = "male";
localStorage.setItem("genderValue","male")
});

$('#girl').on('click',function(){
var genderValue = "female";
localStorage.setItem("genderValue","female");
});
}else{
var genderValue = localStorage.getItem("genderValue");
}
```

> `localStorage` is used to save values on the user's computer. This feature can be very useful, if your game requires many days to get completed. Here in the code above,`genderValue` will be retrieved from the user's computer if the user is not visiting for the first time. However the buttons will still be visible because we have not written the code to hide them. If you want that functionality then please write in the comment section.
>
> See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage for a detailed description as well as usage.

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm wondering though, and this is probably should be put as a new question/post, but how could I use `localstorage` and have a `save game` feature?

Answer (score 1):

Try jquery click handler and selector:

```js
var gendervalue;
$(function() {
  $('a.genderchoice').on('click', function() {
    gendervalue = this.id === "boy" ? "Male" : "Female";
    alert(gendervalue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 id="gender">Are you a <a href="#" id="boy" class="genderchoice">boy</a> or a <a href="#" id="girl" class="genderchoice">girl</a>?</h3>
```